# Signed Mac App's "Running" but not running (XCode 4)

Tags: cocoa, macos, xcode4, code-signing

I just moved to developing Mac Apps from iOS apps. I create even the most basic apps - run them - all is well.
As soon as I add a Code Signing Identity (with certificate I created and have no problems with) - the app builds successfully, XCode says "Running " - but it never runs.

I tried cleaning, closing/reopening XCode, rebooting...

Any help will be immensely appreciated

**UPDATE**
Ok - I've managed to figure out it's a conflict between Lion 10.7.1 (that doesn't support iCloud yet) and the provision that is set to enable iCloud
As of Lion 10.7.2 the problem has been fixed

Comment: Do you see anything in Console?

Comment: nope - clean as a whistle:
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
[Switching to process 1587 thread 0x0]
kill
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: How about the system logs in the Console app?

Comment: wow - some funky stuff there - when I run it I get sandbox erros regarding Security reading from SQLite db of certificates - namely: 
taskgated-helper(1928) deny file-read-metadata /private/var/db/DetachedSignatures

Comment: Is your code signing certificate actually trusted (did it come from the developer portal)?

Comment: yup - created and submitted certificate signing request and got mac developer and installed certificates, they both installed fine in keychain and provision didn't have a problem either

Comment: You might have better luck if you try asking on http://devforums.apple.com.

Comment: 3 people had already asked with not answer... but I'll keep looking and post back when I crack it. Thanks for the patience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a provision to XCode is not enough - I forgot to install the provision on the computer itself.

But in my defense - unlike in iOS/iTunes - there was no indicative message.

Comment: What exactly did you do to get it working? Add Mac Team Profile to the "Profiles"? Are you running 10.7.2?

Comment: Well I got it working on my local computer by actually installing the provision, but I can't install it on other computers most likely because of the lack of 10.7.2...
Waiting for the official release because I don't have patience for the frequent updates